# Finding the normal of manifold in $\mathbb{R}^3$ (Divergence theorem)

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, manifolds, divergence-operator

> Calculate $\oint_\gamma f(X) dX$ where $f(x,y,z) = (yz,xz,xy)$, 
>   $\gamma = \{X(t)| 0 \le t \le 2\pi\}$, $X(t) = (cos(t)cos(\frac{\pi}{8} + \frac{t(2\pi-t)}{4\pi}),sin(t)cos(\frac{\pi}{8} + \frac{t(2\pi-t)}{4\pi}),sin(\frac{\pi}{8} + \frac{t(2\pi-t)}{4\pi}))$

I know that I need to use the Divergence theorem(that's the subject of the exercise). I want to calculate the normal $N(x)$ of the manifold $\gamma$, so I could try and get anything close to $\oint_\gamma f(X)dX$ in the form of $\int<F,N> dx$ where $F$ is some vector field (and then use the Divergence theorem).

I know that usually the normal of manifold which is given by parameterization is $N(x)=\frac{r_{u_1}\times\dots\times r_{u_{n-1}}}{||r_{u_1}\times\dots\times r_{u_{n-1}}||}$ (Where $r(U)$ is the parameterization) but here I'm given a parameterization that operate over single variable, $t$.

How does that formula for the normal $N(x)$ works in that case? Or perhaps is there any other way to calculate the normal?

Or is there any other trick that I'm missing to use the Divergence theorem with the current integral?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given vector field $f$ is nothing else but $f=\nabla F$ for the scalar function $F(x,y,z):=xyz$. We are therefore told to integrate
$$\int_\gamma \nabla F(X)\cdot dX$$
along the curve $$\gamma: \quad t\mapsto X(t):=\bigl(\cos\psi(t)\cos t,\cos\psi(t)\sin t,\sin\psi(t)\bigr)\qquad(0\leq t\leq2\pi)\ ,$$
with $$\psi(t):={\pi\over8}+{t(2\pi -t)\over4\pi}\ ,$$
hence $\psi(0)=\psi(2\pi)={\pi\over8}$. It follows that $\gamma$ begins and ends at the point ${\bf p}:=\gamma(0)=\bigl(\cos{\pi\over8},0,\sin{\pi\over8}\bigr)$. Since $F$ is $C^1$ on all of ${\mathbb R}^3$ this allows to conclude that
$$\int_\gamma \nabla F(X)\cdot dX=F({\bf p})-F({\bf p})=0\ .$$

Comment: I really like your answer! But unfortunately I must use the Divergence theorem. I actually havn't noticed until now that $f=\nabla F$. So $f$ is the normal of the space given by $F=c$, but is it related in any way to our $\gamma$?

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of the exercise is that there is no reason to find the normal to the surface at all!  The "divergence theorem" says that 
$\int\int \vec{F}\cdot\vec{n}dS= \int\int\int \nabla\cdot\vec{F} dV$.

You want to integrate $\nabla\cdot\vec{F}$ over the solid having $\gamma$ as surface.

Comment: Yes but in order to use the theorem, I need to get first to an integral which is of the form $\int\int \vec{F}\cdot\vec{n}dS$, no? and then, use the theorem and calculate $\int\int\int \nabla\cdot\vec{F} dV$ instead. But first I how can I find what $\int\int \vec{F}\cdot\vec{n}dS$ is? I mean, all I know is that I need to calculate $\oint_\gamma f(X)dX$, but I don't know if $\int\int \vec{F}\cdot\vec{n}dS= \oint_\gamma f(X)dX$...

Comment: You **already** have that form!! That's exactly what $\int\int \vec{F}\cdot\vec{n}dS$ is.  You do NOT need to write it out explicitly.  You just need to write $\int\int\int \nabla\cdot \vec{F}dV$ explicitely.

Comment: Why is that exactly what $\int\int \vec{F}\cdot\vec{n} dS$ is?